# Insert HTML table row clone at index without jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to insert a row at the index of the `addmorebutton` td row.

First attempt indeed adds a row at the desired index however not as I would have expected, simply as space vs actually adding a bounded row column box.

How do I insert a new row at the clicked index of `td` that is empty and is indeed apart of the table?

```js
function deleteRow(row) {
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById('Table').deleteRow(i);
}


function addRow() {
  var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementByID('Table').insertRow(i);
}
turkSetAssignmentID();
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
<form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'>
  <input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId' />

  <h1>This is a test</h1>

  <div id="tablediv">
    <input type="button" id="addbutton" value="Add Index" /><br/><br/>
    <table id="Table" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Index</td>
        <td>Measured Depth</td>
        <td>Inclination</td>
        <td>Azimuth</td>
        <td>Delete?</td>
        <td>Add Row?</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="Measured Depth" contenteditable='true'></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="Inclination" contenteditable='true'></td>
        <td><input size=25 type="text" id="Azimuth" contenteditable='true'></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="delbutton" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="addmorebutton" value="Add More Indexs" onclick="addRow.apply(this)" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <p><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Submit' /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The inserted row is completely blank; if you want the same row as your existing 2nd one, you'll have to clone the HTML. Messy example based on your code: https://jsfiddle.net/h4koj4bx/ (you also need to use `name="azimuth[]"` etc. in your `<input>`s in order to properly send the data) ((btw, this question nicely showcases why people built angular, React, etc.))

Comment: @ChrisG thankyou, I am not very familiar with angular and react etc except for the names... your fiddle worked beautifully I appreciate it. and also I appreciate the additional tip for input. I will look into other extensions such as angular.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the respective cells to new row, saving the row on a `var` and the with the `appendChild()` function. Something like this:

```js
function addRow(row) {
      var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex + 1;
      var nextRow = document.getElementById('Table').insertRow(i);

      // Start iterating over all the cells on the row
      var cell = nextRow.insertCell(0);
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
      cell = nextRow.insertCell();
      cell = nextRow.insertCell();
      cell = nextRow.insertCell();
      cell = nextRow.insertCell();
      cell = nextRow.insertCell();
      input = document.createElement("Input");
      input.type = "button";
      input.setAttribute("onclick", "addRow(this)");
      input.value = "Add More Indexs"
      cell.appendChild(input);
    }
```

And of course append on each cell the respective input.
Then maybe you would like to add a function to increase the index number of the rows under the new one...

Also I changed the `onclick` value on the original button to `addRow(this)`.